# SQL Insert Into cannot insert NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have set some script that inserts data from an XML file into a SQL database.  I am getting the following error.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'fighterID', table 'MMA     Database.dbo.FIGHTERStemp'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I have fighterID set as the primary key and will not allow NULLS.  My intention is to have it number each row as they are inserted.  I found one answer that advises to modify the column properties to be the identifier.  However it will not let me adjust the columns properties without dropping and adding the table again.

I can do that - but what is the SQL syntax to set the identity specification settings?  Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: "it will not let me adjust the columns properties without dropping and adding the table again." Where do you see this message? in SSMS? There's a setting in SSMS that stops this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just set the field with datatype `INT` (integer) and follow it with keyword `IDENTITY`.  You can include the `seed` and `increment` values; e.g. start at 1, increment by 1, or just use the keyword `IDENTITY` for a 1,1 default.

```
CREATE TABLE MMA (FighterID INT IDENTITY (1,1), FighterInfo VARCHAR(MAX))
```

Comment: Note: the use of `IDENTITY` implies `NOT NULL` so it is not required to specify it

Comment: Worked to perfection.  Thanks.  Out of curiosity - if this table were to grow such that I wouldn't want a fighterID to be 10,560,123....What is the best way to set up that column.  Maybe to generate a random int/char combination?  I.E. fighterID A12B7

Comment: Depends on what you want the FighterID to represent, how long the fighter stays in the DB, what kind of DB it is, etc.  But yes, there are a lot of different ways you can set it and specify that NULL is an invalid "value".

Answer (score 0):

While inserting data into Primary key you can check the previous max id value and then increment it to next value before you insert a new row.

In SQL, you need to drop table before altering its specification. You can do this by taking backup into temp table then drop your main table and then re insert data from temp table.

Comment: This method suffers from concurrency problems and is not recommended